# Radio button to mysql with ajax validation

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms, radio-button

First off: I'm using the mail script made by Jeffrey Way on In the Woods.

I have a simple form, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="sendEmail.php" id="form_reserveren">
<div id="container">

    <div id="main" style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left;">
        <div class="left">
            <h3>Uw gegevens</h3>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 30px; height: 40px; width: 100%;">
                <input type="radio" id="zml_geslacht" name="zml0" value="de Heer"/><span style="float: left; margin-top: -5px; height: 25px;">de Heer</span><br />
                <input type="radio" id="zml_geslacht" name="zml0" value="Mevrouw"/><span style="float: left; margin-top: -5px; height: 25px;">Mevrouw</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" id="zml_voornaam" name="zml1" value="Uw voornaam" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Uw voornaam';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Uw voornaam') this.value='';"/>
                <input type="text" id="zml_achternaam" name="zml2" value="Uw achternaam *" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Uw achternaam *';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Uw achternaam *') this.value='';"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" id="zml_email" name="zml3" value="Uw e-mailadres *" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Uw e-mailadres *';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Uw e-mailadres *') this.value='';"/>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <h3>Uw reservering</h3>
            <p style="height:68px;">
                <textarea name="zml13" id="zml_opmerkingen" rows="12">Opmerkingen</textarea>
            </p>    


            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Email Us!" /></p>
            <ul id="response" />
        </div>
    </div><!--end main -->

</div><!-- end container -->
</form>
```

This goes through ajax, like so:

```
var zml0 = $('input#zml_geslacht').html( $(':checked').val());
var zml1 = $('input#zml_voornaam').val();
var zml2 = $('input#zml_achternaam').val();
var zml3 = $('input#zml_email').val();
var zml13 = $('textarea#zml_opmerkingen').val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'sendEmail.php',
    data: 'zml0=' + zml0 + '&zml1=' + zml1 + '&zml2=' + zml2 + '&zml3=' + zml3 + '&zml13=' + zml13,

    success: function(results) {
        $('#main img.loaderIcon').fadeOut(1000);
        $('ul#response').html(results);
    }
}); // end ajax
```

And after that it goes to my sendEmail.php to send the form to an e-mailaddress (and store it in a database). The query is:

```
 $zml0 = $_REQUEST['zml0']; // Geslacht

    // database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);


// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (zml0,zml1,zml2) VALUES (:zml0,:zml1,:zml2)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':zml0'=>$zml0,
                  ':zml1'=>$zml1,
                  ':zml2'=>$zml2));
```

Everthing works.. I also have name, e-mailaddress etc, except for the Gender radio buttons (Gender in Dutch is Geslacht, I name it zml0 to have a little more prevention from spammers). The idea of course is that the user should select Female or Male.

When it gets stored in the database, all it says is [object Object]. Also when I just echo out the input. How can I make this work?

Comment: is that the complete html? i don't see the form tag

Comment: No.. That's not the complete form. I can post the complete html form if you want, but I don't want the post to be too big :p

Comment: Are you posting the whole form in the ajax or just this one field?

Comment: As @TimWithers said you should really use `.serialize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var zml0 = $('input[name=zml0]:checked').val();
```

The other thing you could try, which might make your life a little easier for bigger forms is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'sendEmail.php',
    data: $('#form_reserveren').serialize(),

    success: function(results) {
        $('#main img.loaderIcon').fadeOut(1000);
        $('ul#response').html(results);
    }
}); // end ajax
```

Comment: That won't work because it's a global variable. He needs to do that in the ajax call.

Comment: Depends on where it was.  If it was inside a function, then its not global.

Comment: THanks Tim, var zml0 = $('input[name=zml0]:checked').val(); worked.

Comment: @DonMunter I would truly consider using the serialize function as your form gets bigger.

Comment: Alright, I will use that. I might need a little investigation in the serialize function as I don't know yet what it means :p Yeah, the form will be a reservation form with around 12 (not my idea) input fields etc.

Answer (score 1):

This line is the issue:

```
var zml0 = $('input#zml_geslacht').html( $(':checked').val());
```

Appears to be a global variable so if you checked the other box it won't matter. You'd always send the initial value. Well you would if it was correct. The second issue is that you're just grabbing the html? from it, not the actual value. Apparently this is returning an object.

Your ajax call should grab the form input at the time:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'sendEmail.php',
    data: 'zml0=' + $('input[name=zml0]:checked').val(),

    success: function(results) {
        $('#main img.loaderIcon').fadeOut(1000);
        $('ul#response').html(results);
    }
});
```